animation of the quantum harmonic oscillator in Python
I wrote this code to plot the quantum harmonic oscillator wave functions and potential
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x_0 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1,1)
ax1.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 6) 
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('$|\Psi|^2$')
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], "r-")
line2, = ax1.plot([], [])

def init():
    line1.set_data(x_0, x_0**2)
    return line1,

def animate(i):
    line2.set_data(x_0 , wf_list[i])
    return line1,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(wf_list), 
                              init_func=init, blit=True,
                              interval=1)

But for some reason the plot is only showing the potential and the animation is not working, any advice on where the issue is?
The wf_list is an array with the size of 315, and each element is an array itself with the size of 500, i.e the wave function at different times, here is a short version of it with the wave function at the 4 different time steps (and 100 elements each instead of 500):
wf_list = [ [ [0.00039619+0.j],
       [0.00079237+0.j],
       [0.00118851+0.j],
       [0.00158461+0.j],
       [0.00198065+0.j],
       [0.00237661+0.j],
       [0.00277247+0.j],
       [0.00316823+0.j],
       [0.00356386+0.j],
       [0.00395935+0.j],
       [0.00435468+0.j],
       [0.00474985+0.j],
       [0.00514482+0.j],
       [0.0055396 +0.j],
       [0.00593416+0.j],
       [0.00632848+0.j],
       [0.00672255+0.j],
       [0.00711637+0.j],
       [0.0075099 +0.j],
       [0.00790313+0.j],
       [0.00829606+0.j],
       [0.00868865+0.j],
       [0.00908091+0.j],
       [0.00947281+0.j],
       [0.00986434+0.j],
       [0.01025548+0.j],
       [0.01064621+0.j],
       [0.01103653+0.j],
       [0.01142642+0.j],
       [0.01181585+0.j],
       [0.01220482+0.j],
       [0.01259331+0.j],
       [0.0129813 +0.j],
       [0.01336879+0.j],
       [0.01375575+0.j],
       [0.01414216+0.j],
       [0.01452803+0.j],
       [0.01491332+0.j],
       [0.01529802+0.j],
       [0.01568212+0.j],
       [0.01606561+0.j],
       [0.01644846+0.j],
       [0.01683067+0.j],
       [0.01721222+0.j],
       [0.01759308+0.j],
       [0.01797326+0.j],
       [0.01835273+0.j],
       [0.01873148+0.j],
       [0.01910949+0.j],
       [0.01948675+0.j],
       [0.01986325+0.j],
       [0.02023896+0.j],
       [0.02061388+0.j],
       [0.02098798+0.j],
       [0.02136127+0.j],
       [0.02173371+0.j],
       [0.02210529+0.j],
       [0.02247601+0.j],
       [0.02284585+0.j],
       [0.02321478+0.j],
       [0.02358281+0.j],
       [0.0239499 +0.j],
       [0.02431606+0.j],
       [0.02468125+0.j],
       [0.02504548+0.j],
       [0.02540872+0.j],
       [0.02577097+0.j],
       [0.0261322 +0.j],
       [0.0264924 +0.j],
       [0.02685156+0.j],
       [0.02720966+0.j],
       [0.0275667 +0.j],
       [0.02792265+0.j],
       [0.0282775 +0.j],
       [0.02863125+0.j],
       [0.02898386+0.j],
       [0.02933534+0.j],
       [0.02968566+0.j],
       [0.03003481+0.j],
       [0.03038279+0.j],
       [0.03072957+0.j],
       [0.03107514+0.j],
       [0.03141949+0.j],
       [0.0317626 +0.j],
       [0.03210447+0.j],
       [0.03244507+0.j],
       [0.0327844 +0.j],
       [0.03312243+0.j],
       [0.03345917+0.j],
       [0.03379459+0.j],
       [0.03412868+0.j],
       [0.03446143+0.j],
       [0.03479282+0.j],
       [0.03512285+0.j],
       [0.03545149+0.j],
       [0.03577874+0.j],
       [0.03610459+0.j],
       [0.03642901+0.j],
       [0.036752  +0.j],
       [0.03707355+0.j]] , [[0.00031859-2.07552663e-06j],
       [0.00063737-4.15176285e-06j],
       [0.00095649-6.22936546e-06j],
       [0.00127612-8.30893923e-06j],
       [0.00159642-1.03910376e-05j],
       [0.00191753-1.24761637e-05j],
       [0.0022396 -1.45647704e-05j],
       [0.00256275-1.66572615e-05j],
       [0.00288712-1.87539921e-05j],
       [0.00321282-2.08552694e-05j],
       [0.00353996-2.29613527e-05j],
       [0.00386866-2.50724544e-05j],
       [0.004199  -2.71887405e-05j],
       [0.00453109-2.93103307e-05j],
       [0.00486502-3.14372993e-05j],
       [0.00520085-3.35696754e-05j],
       [0.00553868-3.57074435e-05j],
       [0.00587856-3.78505438e-05j],
       [0.00622056-3.99988727e-05j],
       [0.00656473-4.21522835e-05j],
       [0.00691114-4.43105865e-05j],
       [0.00725982-4.64735495e-05j],
       [0.00761082-4.86408985e-05j],
       [0.00796417-5.08123181e-05j],
       [0.0083199 -5.29874519e-05j],
       [0.00867804-5.51659031e-05j],
       [0.0090386 -5.73472350e-05j],
       [0.0094016 -5.95309714e-05j],
       [0.00976705-6.17165975e-05j],
       [0.01013495-6.39035602e-05j],
       [0.0105053 -6.60912691e-05j],
       [0.01087809-6.82790964e-05j],
       [0.01125332-7.04663786e-05j],
       [0.01163097-7.26524162e-05j],
       [0.01201101-7.48364751e-05j],
       [0.01239343-7.70177872e-05j],
       [0.01277819-7.91955512e-05j],
       [0.01316526-8.13689332e-05j],
       [0.0135546 -8.35370681e-05j],
       [0.01394616-8.56990598e-05j],
       [0.01433991-8.78539829e-05j],
       [0.01473578-9.00008831e-05j],
       [0.01513373-9.21387786e-05j],
       [0.01553369-9.42666608e-05j],
       [0.0159356 -9.63834959e-05j],
       [0.0163394 -9.84882256e-05j],
       [0.01674501-1.00579768e-04j],
       [0.01715235-1.02657021e-04j],
       [0.01756136-1.04718859e-04j],
       [0.01797194-1.06764139e-04j],
       [0.01838402-1.08791700e-04j],
       [0.0187975 -1.10800364e-04j],
       [0.01921229-1.12788937e-04j],
       [0.01962831-1.14756213e-04j],
       [0.02004545-1.16700971e-04j],
       [0.02046361-1.18621982e-04j],
       [0.0208827 -1.20518006e-04j],
       [0.0213026 -1.22387797e-04j],
       [0.02172321-1.24230101e-04j],
       [0.02214443-1.26043662e-04j],
       [0.02256613-1.27827220e-04j],
       [0.02298822-1.29579514e-04j],
       [0.02341056-1.31299284e-04j],
       [0.02383305-1.32985274e-04j],
       [0.02425558-1.34636231e-04j],
       [0.02467801-1.36250908e-04j],
       [0.02510023-1.37828067e-04j],
       [0.02552212-1.39366480e-04j],
       [0.02594356-1.40864931e-04j],
       [0.02636443-1.42322216e-04j],
       [0.0267846 -1.43737148e-04j],
       [0.02720395-1.45108559e-04j],
       [0.02762236-1.46435297e-04j],
       [0.0280397 -1.47716233e-04j],
       [0.02845585-1.48950262e-04j],
       [0.0288707 -1.50136304e-04j],
       [0.02928411-1.51273303e-04j],
       [0.02969597-1.52360235e-04j],
       [0.03010616-1.53396107e-04j],
       [0.03051455-1.54379956e-04j],
       [0.03092104-1.55310855e-04j],
       [0.03132551-1.56187914e-04j],
       [0.03172783-1.57010278e-04j],
       [0.03212791-1.57777136e-04j],
       [0.03252562-1.58487714e-04j],
       [0.03292086-1.59141284e-04j],
       [0.03331353-1.59737163e-04j],
       [0.03370352-1.60274711e-04j],
       [0.03409073-1.60753341e-04j],
       [0.03447506-1.61172510e-04j],
       [0.03485641-1.61531730e-04j],
       [0.03523471-1.61830564e-04j],
       [0.03560984-1.62068628e-04j],
       [0.03598174-1.62245592e-04j],
       [0.03635032-1.62361185e-04j],
       [0.0367155 -1.62415190e-04j],
       [0.0370772 -1.62407450e-04j],
       [0.03743536-1.62337867e-04j],
       [0.0377899 -1.62206403e-04j],
       [0.03814078-1.62013081e-04j]] , [[0.00019812-3.29819061e-06j],
       [0.00039652-6.60071140e-06j],
       [0.00059549-9.91172905e-06j],
       [0.00079531-1.32352531e-05j],
       [0.00099622-1.65751419e-05j],
       [0.00119849-1.99351074e-05j],
       [0.00140236-2.33187205e-05j],
       [0.00160807-2.67294144e-05j],
       [0.00181584-3.01704888e-05j],
       [0.0020259 -3.36451130e-05j],
       [0.00223848-3.71563283e-05j],
       [0.00245376-4.07070506e-05j],
       [0.00267197-4.43000724e-05j],
       [0.00289329-4.79380639e-05j],
       [0.00311792-5.16235748e-05j],
       [0.00334604-5.53590346e-05j],
       [0.00357784-5.91467535e-05j],
       [0.00381347-6.29889224e-05j],
       [0.00405311-6.68876128e-05j],
       [0.00429693-7.08447770e-05j],
       [0.00454507-7.48622470e-05j],
       [0.00479769-7.89417337e-05j],
       [0.00505493-8.30848265e-05j],
       [0.00531692-8.72929915e-05j],
       [0.00558381-9.15675703e-05j],
       [0.00585571-9.59097788e-05j],
       [0.00613275-1.00320705e-04j],
       [0.00641505-1.04801307e-04j],
       [0.0067027 -1.09352412e-04j],
       [0.00699581-1.13974714e-04j],
       [0.00729449-1.18668771e-04j],
       [0.00759881-1.23435003e-04j],
       [0.00790886-1.28273689e-04j],
       [0.00822473-1.33184968e-04j],
       [0.00854647-1.38168832e-04j],
       [0.00887415-1.43225127e-04j],
       [0.00920782-1.48353548e-04j],
       [0.00954755-1.53553641e-04j],
       [0.00989336-1.58824794e-04j],
       [0.0102453 -1.64166242e-04j],
       [0.01060338-1.69577060e-04j],
       [0.01096763-1.75056160e-04j],
       [0.01133806-1.80602295e-04j],
       [0.01171468-1.86214050e-04j],
       [0.01209748-1.91889846e-04j],
       [0.01248644-1.97627933e-04j],
       [0.01288155-2.03426392e-04j],
       [0.01328278-2.09283133e-04j],
       [0.01369008-2.15195895e-04j],
       [0.01410342-2.21162240e-04j],
       [0.01452274-2.27179558e-04j],
       [0.01494798-2.33245064e-04j],
       [0.01537905-2.39355798e-04j],
       [0.01581589-2.45508623e-04j],
       [0.0162584 -2.51700228e-04j],
       [0.01670648-2.57927128e-04j],
       [0.01716002-2.64185663e-04j],
       [0.01761891-2.70472000e-04j],
       [0.01808302-2.76782134e-04j],
       [0.01855222-2.83111892e-04j],
       [0.01902635-2.89456930e-04j],
       [0.01950527-2.95812742e-04j],
       [0.01998881-3.02174656e-04j],
       [0.02047681-3.08537842e-04j],
       [0.02096907-3.14897313e-04j],
       [0.02146542-3.21247930e-04j],
       [0.02196565-3.27584405e-04j],
       [0.02246957-3.33901306e-04j],
       [0.02297694-3.40193064e-04j],
       [0.02348756-3.46453975e-04j],
       [0.02400119-3.52678207e-04j],
       [0.02451759-3.58859809e-04j],
       [0.02503652-3.64992714e-04j],
       [0.02555772-3.71070747e-04j],
       [0.02608093-3.77087633e-04j],
       [0.02660589-3.83037005e-04j],
       [0.02713233-3.88912411e-04j],
       [0.02765996-3.94707325e-04j],
       [0.02818849-4.00415154e-04j],
       [0.02871765-4.06029246e-04j],
       [0.02924712-4.11542906e-04j],
       [0.02977662-4.16949397e-04j],
       [0.03030583-4.22241959e-04j],
       [0.03083445-4.27413815e-04j],
       [0.03136217-4.32458183e-04j],
       [0.03188867-4.37368290e-04j],
       [0.03241364-4.42137380e-04j],
       [0.03293675-4.46758729e-04j],
       [0.03345769-4.51225654e-04j],
       [0.03397613-4.55531532e-04j],
       [0.03449176-4.59669805e-04j],
       [0.03500425-4.63633999e-04j],
       [0.03551328-4.67417733e-04j],
       [0.03601854-4.71014738e-04j],
       [0.0365197 -4.74418863e-04j],
       [0.03701645-4.77624094e-04j],
       [0.03750848-4.80624566e-04j],
       [0.03799549-4.83414578e-04j],
       [0.03847717-4.85988605e-04j],
       [0.03895322-4.88341309e-04j]] , [[0.00010626-3.12595618e-06j],
       [0.00021279-6.25947411e-06j],
       [0.00031985-9.40789297e-06j],
       [0.00042769-1.25783475e-05j],
       [0.00053657-1.57777847e-05j],
       [0.00064673-1.90129787e-05j],
       [0.00075841-2.22905448e-05j],
       [0.00087184-2.56169515e-05j],
       [0.00098724-2.89985318e-05j],
       [0.00110486-3.24414932e-05j],
       [0.0012249 -3.59519260e-05j],
       [0.00134759-3.95358115e-05j],
       [0.00147314-4.31990283e-05j],
       [0.00160177-4.69473579e-05j],
       [0.0017337 -5.07864896e-05j],
       [0.00186912-5.47220241e-05j],
       [0.00200825-5.87594762e-05j],
       [0.00215129-6.29042771e-05j],
       [0.00229846-6.71617755e-05j],
       [0.00244994-7.15372378e-05j],
       [0.00260594-7.60358479e-05j],
       [0.00276667-8.06627061e-05j],
       [0.00293231-8.54228270e-05j],
       [0.00310307-9.03211372e-05j],
       [0.00327914-9.53624719e-05j],
       [0.00346072-1.00551571e-04j],
       [0.00364798-1.05893075e-04j],
       [0.00384113-1.11391519e-04j],
       [0.00404035-1.17051327e-04j],
       [0.00424583-1.22876807e-04j],
       [0.00445774-1.28872143e-04j],
       [0.00467626-1.35041385e-04j],
       [0.00490159-1.41388446e-04j],
       [0.00513388-1.47917091e-04j],
       [0.00537331-1.54630927e-04j],
       [0.00562004-1.61533395e-04j],
       [0.00587425-1.68627759e-04j],
       [0.00613608-1.75917097e-04j],
       [0.0064057 -1.83404288e-04j],
       [0.00668325-1.91092005e-04j],
       [0.00696888-1.98982699e-04j],
       [0.00726273-2.07078590e-04j],
       [0.00756493-2.15381654e-04j],
       [0.00787561-2.23893611e-04j],
       [0.00819489-2.32615912e-04j],
       [0.00852289-2.41549728e-04j],
       [0.00885971-2.50695932e-04j],
       [0.00920545-2.60055095e-04j],
       [0.00956021-2.69627464e-04j],
       [0.00992406-2.79412954e-04j],
       [0.01029707-2.89411133e-04j],
       [0.01067932-2.99621209e-04j],
       [0.01107086-3.10042018e-04j],
       [0.01147172-3.20672011e-04j],
       [0.01188195-3.31509241e-04j],
       [0.01230157-3.42551348e-04j],
       [0.01273058-3.53795552e-04j],
       [0.01316898-3.65238637e-04j],
       [0.01361677-3.76876942e-04j],
       [0.01407391-3.88706347e-04j],
       [0.01454036-4.00722268e-04j],
       [0.01501608-4.12919638e-04j],
       [0.01550099-4.25292909e-04j],
       [0.01599501-4.37836033e-04j],
       [0.01649805-4.50542460e-04j],
       [0.01701   -4.63405128e-04j],
       [0.01753073-4.76416459e-04j],
       [0.01806009-4.89568351e-04j],
       [0.01859794-5.02852176e-04j],
       [0.0191441 -5.16258772e-04j],
       [0.01969837-5.29778446e-04j],
       [0.02026056-5.43400968e-04j],
       [0.02083044-5.57115574e-04j],
       [0.02140778-5.70910965e-04j],
       [0.02199232-5.84775309e-04j],
       [0.02258378-5.98696247e-04j],
       [0.02318188-6.12660894e-04j],
       [0.02378632-6.26655850e-04j],
       [0.02439677-6.40667203e-04j],
       [0.02501289-6.54680541e-04j],
       [0.02563434-6.68680962e-04j],
       [0.02626073-6.82653088e-04j],
       [0.02689169-6.96581075e-04j],
       [0.02752681-7.10448634e-04j],
       [0.02816568-7.24239043e-04j],
       [0.02880787-7.37935168e-04j],
       [0.02945292-7.51519484e-04j],
       [0.03010038-7.64974098e-04j],
       [0.03074978-7.78280769e-04j],
       [0.03140063-7.91420940e-04j],
       [0.03205243-8.04375757e-04j],
       [0.03270467-8.17126107e-04j],
       [0.03335683-8.29652640e-04j],
       [0.03400839-8.41935808e-04j],
       [0.03465879-8.53955896e-04j],
       [0.0353075 -8.65693056e-04j],
       [0.03595396-8.77127346e-04j],
       [0.03659761-8.88238770e-04j],
       [0.03723787-8.99007312e-04j],
       [0.03787418-9.09412984e-04j]] ]


Please add a [mre]

I just updated the post!:)

Yes, but not with a [mre]. If I copy your code and paste it into python I get a NameError: name 'np' is not defined and I'm quite sure that there are more things that will not work without at least some imports.

Ohh you're totally right, sorry I'm new to this! i updated the question again, hopefully it will work now:)

Try removing the "Blit=True" parameter. (Also, change the y scale ... and change the y label to whatever you are plotting from a complex array).

For your test data, at least, also change the amount of data in x_0 to 100, replace wf_list[i] by np.real( wf_list[i] ), change the y limit to something much smaller and make sure that you have plt.show() at the end. Then it "works" (after a fashion).
